# wxPython - SetLabel doesn't trigger on passing values between classes

Tags: oop, wxpython

I'm trying to pass values between classes in wxPython and seems to be working (the value passed prints to the console) but I don't know why `bottomLabel` doesn't change its value - the arguments are passed properly but the `changeLabel()` method doesn't update label.

Here's the code:

```
import wx

class TopPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Main.btm = BottomPanel(parent=parent)

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label='Choose your animal:', pos=(10, 30))
        animals = ["dog", "cat", "mouse"]
        self.combobox = wx.ComboBox(self, choices=animals, pos=(10, 50))
        self.label2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="", pos=(10, 80))
        self.combobox.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onCombo)


    def onCombo(self, event):
        comboValue = self.combobox.GetValue()
        self.label2.SetLabel("Chosen animal: " + comboValue)
        Main.animal = comboValue
        Main.btm.changeLabel(event, comboValue)


class BottomPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("grey")
        self.bottomLabel = wx.StaticText(self, label="MyBottomLabel", pos=(10, 50))

    def changeLabel(self, event, passedText):
        self.bottomLabel.SetLabel(passedText)
        print(passedText)

class Main(wx.Frame):
    btm=None
    animal = ""

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Generator", size=(500, 500))
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        top = TopPanel(splitter)
        bottom = BottomPanel(splitter)
        splitter.SplitHorizontally(top, bottom)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(250)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I'm quite new to OOP in Python so sorry if the code isn't the most elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have picked a particularly tortured example, as the parent to panels is not `Main` but the `splitter` and you have declared everything in `Main` as local variables, by not using `self`.
Here is `a` quick way to do it. You'll notice I had to declare `bottom` before `top` otherwise it doesn't exist when `TopPanel` is declared. I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this.

```
import wx

class TopPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        Main = parent.GetParent()
        self.btm = Main.bottom
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label='Choose your animal:', pos=(10, 30))
        animals = ["dog", "cat", "mouse"]
        self.combobox = wx.ComboBox(self, choices=animals, pos=(10, 50))
        self.label2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="", pos=(10, 80))
        self.combobox.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onCombo)


    def onCombo(self, event):
        comboValue = self.combobox.GetValue()
        self.label2.SetLabel("Chosen animal: " + comboValue)
        self.btm.changeLabel(event, comboValue)


class BottomPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("grey")
        self.bottomLabel = wx.StaticText(self, label="MyBottomLabel", pos=(10, 50))

    def changeLabel(self, event, passedText):
        self.bottomLabel.SetLabel(passedText)
        print(passedText)

class Main(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Generator", size=(500, 500))
        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.bottom = BottomPanel(self.splitter)
        self.top = TopPanel(self.splitter)
        self.splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.top, self.bottom)
        self.splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(250)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]